# All possible flat conformal metrics of dimension greater than 2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

Combining [List of formulas in Riemannian geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Under_a_conformal_change) and [Conformal symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_symmetry#Generators_and_commutation_relations), is there a proof which states
$$
   x^\mu \to \frac{x^\mu-a^\mu x^2}{1 - 2a\cdot x + a^2 x^2}
$$
represents all possible one-to-one conformally flat transformations $\tilde{g}_{mn}=e^{2\varphi}g_{mn}$, where both metrics are flat. Flat means the Riemann tensor $R_{ijkl}$ is zero.
$$
\tilde R_{ijkl} = e^{2\varphi}\left( R_{ijkl} - \left[ g {~\wedge\!\!\!\!\!\!\bigcirc~} \left( \nabla\partial\varphi - \partial\varphi\partial\varphi + \frac{1}{2}\|\nabla\varphi\|^2g    \right)\right]_{ijkl}  \right)
$$